# What does "gold" mean in NLP?

Tags: nlp

The NLP papers mention 'gold paragraph' and 'gold annotated chains'. I can probably understand what "gold" means, but it's not entirely clear.

Answer (score 1):

This is related to the concept of gold standard.
As stated [here](https://port.sas.ac.uk/mod/book/view.php?id=612&chapterid=426):

> [Gold standard] is a dataset which has been annotated (either manually
> or automatically) and then manually corrected.

Basically, the gold standard is the comparison reference for your nlp algorithm, the one you use to calculate evaluation performance.

For example, in a NER task, the gold standard are the NER tags that manually annotate in the text, the ones that you would like your NER algorithm to find out.